# Get refresh tokens of Microsoft Graph API with OAuthPrompt

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm creating a MS Teams bot which periodically checks the users' Outlook calendar by background threads spawned after the user logs in via [`OAuthPrompt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/oauthprompt?view=botbuilder-ts-latest).

To implement the feature, it seems that I have to configure an OAuth connection setting and an app registration supporting `offline_access`. Then, get a refresh token when getting an access token, according to [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/graph/auth-v2-user).

But as long as I tried [the example bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/18.bot-authentication), the result of `OAuthPrompt` doesn't contain a refresh token. And I couldn't find the documented way to get it.

How can I achieve the goal? Do I need some hack on `OAuthPrompt` or some related classes? Do I have to build cards from scratch?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this, I'm also having the same issue.

Comment: I got an idea yesterday (but not yet implemented!). Currently I'm trying to get the user's chat list by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http after the user logs in via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node?tutorial-step=3 (like an ordinary  web app), then find the chat where bot and the user actually talk.

Comment: Let me add one more:  This is sufficient for my case because we can get refresh tokens like an oridinary web app, and the bot can recognize who has logged in thanks to the Teams' API.

Comment: So instead of oAuthPrompt, you are using a regular sign in process in the bot, is it working as expected?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I tested with the Teams' API today, there's no documented way to get suitable information from Teams' API... So I voted for an idea: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/40761184-contain-bots-in-the-result-of-the-list-conversatio Please for it if you like!

Comment: But at the same time I found that the `id`s returned by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http consist of the user's `aadObjectId` and the bot's `MicrosoftAppId`. I'm going to make a POC to associate the id with `conversationReference` next week!

Comment: As I answered by myself. I finally implemented the feature! After experimenting with Teams API, I found we don't actually have to use Teams API...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concluded that we can't get `refresh_token` with `OAuthPrompt` from investigation. So I made up with a different way to achieve the goal.
The key idea is creating a tiny web app just for the "Sign in with Microsoft account" feature, which can easily get `refresh_token` as ordinary web apps.

Here is the example app: https://github.com/igrep/example-teams-bot-with-ms-account-refresh-token

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info. So if I'm not wrong, from the bot end you present a user with "card" with URL set to the web app created and discard usage of oAuthPrompt. Is this correct? Are you displaying the signin in a popup window?

Comment: Sorry, one more quick question, are you using AADV2 or AADV2?

Comment: It should be Azure AD v2.

Answer (score 1):

The sample which you are using is for most of the channels, but Teams behaves differently. **An Invoke Activity is sent to the bot rather than the Event Activity used by other channels**. This Invoke Activity must be forwarded to the dialog if the OAuthPrompt is being used.

- Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample) documentation for adding authentication to your MS Teams bot, which makes use of [Teams-auth](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth) sample.
- For a better understanding of how OAuth works in MS Teams, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-bot) documentation which explains the authentication flow.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

alwaysPrompt flag should be false. Then OAuth prompt will get refresh tokens silently without prompting login card.
Please refer the answer on github about this isse.

[Bot composer OAuth refresh token](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/3629)

Comment: Your solution works only when the user keeps talking with the bot because OAuthPrompt is designed for use in a dialog. OAuthPrompt can't pass either the refreshed access token or refresh token to my background thread, which isn't even a part of the bot.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea has flashed into my mind while writing [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62441914/get-refresh-tokens-of-microsoft-graph-api-with-oauthprompt/62669632#comment111321245_62947673): running a dialog including `OAuthPrompt` in a `TurnContext` made with a `ConversationRefrence`, which is saved and passed to the background thread, may work. (But I have no time and no motive to try!)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed the refresh_token to get access tokens for other Microsoft resources like Exchange,
the solution was to use

```
      const tokenResponses = await context.adapter.getAadTokens(context, this.connectionName, [
     "https://outlook.office365.com",
     "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  ]);
```